# What's the point of using @RenderBody in a MVC Razor view?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

In my MVC4 razor layout I am using `@RenderSection` and I don't bother
with `@RenderBody`.

Then in the views I just place everything in sections.

This makes me wonder what's the point of `@RenderBody` other than to 
make it easier for people who don't want to put things in sections. Is there anything different from `@RenderBody` and something inside a `@RenderSection`?

Answer (score 22):

`@RenderBody` renders the content of your  page that is *not within any named sections.*  If **all** of your content is within one of your defined sections, there is no point.  However...

In Razor syntax, `@RenderSection` replaces master pages.  It allows you to carve out sections of the page for particular areas, and then allow the main body of the content to emerge naturally wherever the `@RenderBody` declaration is placed.

Let's say you are writing an invoice.  The `RenderBody` area would the that part of the page that contains your invoice line items.  This is true of most reports; there's always a header section, a body section and a footer section.

Presumably, rendering a section in the appropriate area of a web page allows you to obtain proper semantic behavior, such as styling the footer in a way that it always appears at the bottom of a page.

```
<footer>
  @RenderSection("Footer", @<span>This is my footer!</span>)
</footer>
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vs2010trainingcourse_aspnetmvc3razor_topic2.aspx

http://haacked.com/archive/2011/03/05/defining-default-content-for-a-razor-layout-section.aspx

Comment: Thanks - I thought so. Just wondering if there was any special caching or anything with the RenderBody. Personally if I have more than one section I think it's a bit cleaner to keep everything in sections rather than use the RenderBody for one and sections for the other.

Comment: See my edit....  RenderBody allows you to render the ordinary content into a page having sections, without requiring you to maintain another defined section just for the main content.  This is how all reports work... The main content body should not need any awareness of the sections on the rest of the page.  That way, you can render the body as an ordinary web page without the other sections (and without defining a "body section"), or render it into a page with different sections altogether, and it will still work.